# What might cause this error in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app and I got this error after 2-5mins I launched the application.
What is this?

```
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894): Build fingerprint: 'google/passion_kt/passion:2.3.3/GRI40/49208:user/release-keys'
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894): pid: 2956, tid: 2956  >>> com.company.app.p2p <<<
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 45088dbc
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894):  r0 42089000  r1 ffffffff  r2 00000000  r3 ffffffff
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894):  r4 20000000  r5 e8001200  r6 40009228  r7 00000001
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894):  r8 4051a3f8  r9 800a5600  10 80000000  fp 00000001
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894):  ip 00bfff6f  sp beb28d08  lr 80036028  pc 80035938  cpsr a0000010
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894):  d0  0000000000056b17  d1  6c675f6c6c6f7200
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894):  d2  6d6172662f6d6528  d3  72662f6b726f7707
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894):  d6  0000000000000000  d7  4080000000000000
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894):  d8  0000a27fb5b4b66f  d9  4325d5f141400000
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894):  d10 4269198840557fe0  d11 0000000042391988
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894):  d16 002b09c8000000a0  d17 bff0000000000000
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894):  d18 3ff0000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894):  d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894):  d22 3ff0000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894):  d24 3ff0000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894):  d28 0100010001000100  d29 3ff8000000000000
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 3fe5555555555555
05-26 18:51:08.137: INFO/DEBUG(2894):  scr 60000012
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):          #00  pc 00035938  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):          #01  pc 00036024  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):          #02  pc 000368cc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):          #03  pc 00020350  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894): code around pc:
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894): 80035918 e065c003 e1530007 85803010 e5900000 
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894): 80035928 e1e051ac e1a0c42c e205701f e1a0771b 
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894): 80035938 e790510c e1170005 e1875005 e780510c 
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894): 80035948 1a00000c e5960014 e1530000 35960008 
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894): 80035958 3240c004 3586c008 35003004 e59d3004 
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894): code around lr:
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894): 80036008 0a000001 e3a02000 eb014474 e596209c 
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894): 80036018 eaffffd1 e1a01005 e1a00006 ebfffe1c 
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894): 80036028 e596102c e3510001 d8bd87f0 e5962058 
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894): 80036038 e3520000 d8bd87f0 e3a04000 e3a0a001 
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894): 80036048 e596305c e7931104 e3510000 0a000020 
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894): stack:
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28cc8  00000001  
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28ccc  4342cbe0  
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28cd0  000001e4  
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28cd4  00000004  
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28cd8  42263150  
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28cdc  4342cbdb  
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28ce0  44707fd0  
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28ce4  8008eb86  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28ce8  00000007  
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28cec  002d7c02  
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28cf0  00000007  
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28cf4  8005e489  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28cf8  42263150  
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28cfc  00000004  
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28d00  df002777  
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28d04  e3a070ad  
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894): #00 beb28d08  80089a63  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28d0c  fffffe84  
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28d10  44707fe4  
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28d14  4051a518  
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28d18  40009228  
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28d1c  4051a3f8  
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28d20  800a5600  
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28d24  fffffe84  
05-26 18:51:08.207: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28d28  00000001  
05-26 18:51:08.217: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28d2c  0000000c  
05-26 18:51:08.217: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28d30  4051a400  
05-26 18:51:08.217: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28d34  80036028  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-26 18:51:08.217: INFO/DEBUG(2894): #01 beb28d38  00005113  
05-26 18:51:08.217: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28d3c  40009228  
05-26 18:51:08.217: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28d40  00511400  
05-26 18:51:08.217: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28d44  00000000  
05-26 18:51:08.217: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28d48  400092fc  
05-26 18:51:08.217: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28d4c  80000000  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-26 18:51:08.217: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28d50  400091e8  
05-26 18:51:08.217: INFO/DEBUG(2894):     beb28d54  800368d0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
```

Comment: where is the error? i only see info/debug log

Comment: It terminates the application with this message...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Signal 11 (SIGSEGV) is the signal sent to a process when it makes an invalid memory reference, or segmentation fault. In Android, it's quite often caused by something like a WebView or plugin trying to use more memory than is available, but all sorts of things can potentially cause it -- especially when working with the NDK. Trying to free() memory that has already been released, for example, or just a dangling pointer. A few examples:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/8d083a0ccebe0faa?pli=1

[What is SEGV_MAPERR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000002/what-is-segv-maperr)

[SIGNAL 11 SIGSEGV crash Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973310/signal-11-sigsegv-crash-android-solved)

[Catch Flash out-of-memory error in WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069866/catch-flash-out-of-memory-error-signal-11-in-webview)

Unfortunately, the specific problem cannot be determined from the information available here.