# Prevent Flash Player fault in WebView, as is done by the Android Browser

Tags: android, webview, flash, segmentation-fault

I'm loading **.swf** files into a WebView directly using `webView.loadUrl("http://whatever.com/file.swf");`. It works perfectly in the vast majority of cases.

When loading a few specific **swf** files on certain devices, though, shortly after the Flash media begins to be displayed, my app closes with a Signal 11 fault caused by the Flash Player plugin. **[Example LogCat dump here](http://pastebin.com/drx0ckT9)**. No Exception is thrown. The same thing happens if I load those files into the *xScope browser*.

When loading them into *Dolphin Browser* or the *default Android Browser*, however, shortly after the media begins to be displayed, the following is printed to LogCat:

```
05-31 18:13:15.498: DEBUG/FONT(9183): WARNING: **************************** Detect FLEngine error 1 ****************************
05-31 18:13:15.558: DEBUG/(9183): ---------------------------------------------------------------> call AudioTrack stop()
```

and an error icon is displayed on-screen:

[image: Flash Player plugin error icon in stock Android browser]

No SIGSEGV fault occurs, and the browser is not terminated.

---

Does anyone know how I could do the exact same thing? Prevent the Flash Player plugin from causing the SIGSEGV fault, and simply handle the error myself, without the app being terminated? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No one knows? If Dolphin Browser does it, presumably it must be possible?

Comment: What are the swfs? Are they just animations or are they full applications? Can you offer more information on this please. Are they dependent on any other files? What version are they AS2 or AS3?

Comment: Hi Neil -- The application is a sort of browser that loads SWF animations from multiple web sites. Since any file can be loaded, I don't know what AS versions they'll be using, but the files I've found problems with have not had any external dependencies. Some animations play for a minute or so before causing the SIGSEGV fault. One example is here (note that it runs fine on some devices): http://www.weebls-stuff.com/flash/426_narwhales2.swf

Comment: Actually, I've just found that a *few* files (not the one mentioned above) will terminate the stock Android browser and Dolphin Browser, as well, at least with the HTC version of the Flash plugin.

Comment: Use something like Charles web debugging proxy to check the assets, try and see if there is anything common about them. The narwhales2.swf is player 9 25fps for example. Also you would be able to tell if there are any other files loading in etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see in your logcat output that the crash occurs in libflashlite.so. You should be using real Flash 10.3 or higher, not Flash Lite. The Flash player is available on the Android Market now.

Comment: Unfortunately, a surprisingly high number of Android 2.2+ devices are unable to access Flash 10.x from the market, or even install it manually (many HTC devices for example). While I may know it's the fault of the manufacturer, that doesn't stop users from leaving negative ratings/comments because of crashes. Thanks, though, that probably is the cause of the errors. Just wish I knew what method the Android Browser and Dolphin Browser use to work around the problem.